How to move django models to new server
I have two options and not know which is the best:
1 - After coping Django files, delete migration files, so after makemigrations and migrate tables will be created. And after that import dumped database (only data).
or
2 - Import dumped database (full), everything (create tables and data).

In my opinion, move project with migration files is better, because you copy all lifecycle of developing, then you can just update database using existing migrations. Also, you will have option to rollback to previous migration on new database or do retrospective on bugs using migrations. If you make migration on moved database you will lose those oportunities
